# How to determine the optimal threshold for my classification problem using fpr ,tpr values for each classification record?

Tags: auc, model-evaluation, threshold

The output of my prediction using classification algorithm is in dataframe that contains TPR and FPR value for each prediction. Suppose I have 100 records for prediction then in that cade my data frame consist of 100 records with corresponding FPR and TPR values. Looking at this values I can plot AUC, but how can i determine the optimal threshold to use for my prediction?